# Harnessing AsmXML with Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, fasm

[AsmXML](http://mkerbiquet.free.fr/) written by Marc Kerbiquet seems to be promising as an xml parser. I want to harness it further with Delphi but I stumble because of an object format compatibily issue. Is it possible to tweak the fasm source code to fix the trouble or should it ported to Tasm32 ?

Comment: Why not link to a DLL and go from there? But a native parser would seem more useful than asm.

Comment: I'm going a bit out of topic, but you could also go for a Delphi parser http://www.omnixml.com/ like @DavidHeffernan suggested. OmniXML is fast and very nice written, not to mention the other great features that comes with it, I don't know how slow or fast is in comparison with AsmXml.

Comment: @@ David Hefferman & Dorin Dumininca : You are right, I'm very statisfied using SimpleStorage and FluentXml on top of Omnixml processing Gpx and HR-Xml files. Assembly parser authors boast all the time unbeatable performance and I want to check that by myself. I searched in vain material (workbench and so on) related to that within the Delphi community so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to convert it to be compiled by Delphi.

You can simply use the generated object files then convert it to .obj using some tool like the one [provided here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).

Then the small `asm-xml.h` can be converted to a small Delphi unit, calling the external .obj files. Then you'll have a new unit.

Put I doubt it will be worth it. For instance, you'll loose 64 bit compilation. Parsing and inlining the data is a very common pattern for best speed. I've used a similar technique for JSON in pure pascal, and it is very fast - see [JSON vs XML parsing speed in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304157/json-vs-xml-parsing-speed-in-delphi)

This parser is very fast, but also very simple, and IMHO lacks a lot of XML related functionalities. The bottleneck won't be parsing, but storing or searching, in most cases.

Comment: @@Arnaud Bouchez :Thank you for answering. I've grabbed objconv from the net and spotted in the pdf documentation matter relevant to Borland delphi pascal.

Comment: I still hope to hear more from people having successfully used fasm assembly code (linked) with Delphi be it in production or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to link you to two articles of mine, describing [how to use .obj files with Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html) (but currently only for 32 bit) and [how to use NASM (sorry, not FASM) with Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-nasm.html). They also mention the tools you might need, like *objconv*.